# SharePoint 2016 Online Information List out of sync

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, user-information-list

Help!

I'm adding users to SP Security Groups but they aren't updating on the Information List so users keep getting the Request Access page when then click on a link.

First and most important how can fix this and secondly why did it happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Security groups directly in SharePoint site collection to grant access to the users in this group.

The Security groups you create in Office365 Admin center will not be recognized by that SharePoint site collection.

Reference:

[Create, edit, or delete a security group in the Microsoft 365 admin center.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/email/create-edit-or-delete-a-security-group)

Comment: The SP groups are in the site collection. I've got a SP group in the site collection called Members which has Contribute permissions. User BH is in that group but he's not showing up in the Information List so they keep getting the 'Access Request' page when they click on the link to the site. How could I get BH to show up in the Information List so that they can get access?

Comment: @darrenfloyd666 How did you create this group in the site collection? To grant access to User BH to this site, you can navigate to Site settings > Site permissions and grant Contribute permission directly to this user. You can also create a new group via Site settings > Site permissions > Create group and then add this user to this new group to see the result.

Comment: That’s not what the document you linked says.  It says the opposite: “Security groups can be used with SharePoint, Exchange, MDM, Windows and more.”

Comment: @GregW Yes, the group can be used across the environment, but being put in a security group under admin center won’t give the user access in a SharePoint site unless the group itself has been granted with access permission.

Comment: Your comment says the group itself needs to be created in the site collection directly.  I think you mean the group needs to be granted permissions in the site directly.

Comment: @GregW Exactly.